# get gradle to ignore version number in jar name

Tags: gradle

I have a project that has to build about 10 different dummy jars for unit testing.  I have a gradle project setup like this

```
project(':CodeTools_dummydriver-true') {
    ext.dummyDriver = true
    archivesBaseName = "dummydriver-true"
}
```

But the problem is the jarfile is still named dummydriver-true-0.0.1.jar.  Is there any way I can tell gradle to ignore the standard pattern and please name the output file what I want it to be named?  Meaning, without the version number?

Answer (score 9):

For newer gradle you should use:

`build.gradle.kts`:

```
tasks.jar {
    archiveFileName.set("${project.name}-new-name.jar")
}
```

`build.gradle`:

```
jar.archiveFileName = "new-name.jar"
```

Because `archiveName` is deprecated. (You have to specify `.jar` as well).

Answer (score 8):

The Java plugin [defines the jar task](http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.tasks.bundling.Jar.html) to follow the following template for `archiveName`:

```
${baseName}-${appendix}-${version}-${classifier}.${extension}
```

I don't think there's a way to apply a new "naming template", but what you can do is to explicitly set your jar task's archive name, like this. (Also, isn't it a good idea to use the `dummyDriver` property directly, instead of hardcoding "true" into the archive name?)

```
archivesBaseName = "dummydriver"
jar.archiveName = "${jar.baseName}-${dummyDriver}.${jar.extension}"
```

Alternately, set the `version` property to null or an empty string, like suggested in Circadian's answer, but if you ever want to use the `version` property for anything, you don't want to destroy it.

Answer (score 3):

Adding a version property and setting its value to an empty string worked for me.

Here is an example:

```
project(':CodeTools_dummydriver-true') {
    ext.dummyDriver = true
    archivesBaseName = "dummydriver-true"
    version= ""
}
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Can also set it to `null`.